# Swift using CollectionType .filter .indexOf and .map to find values in an array of tuples

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tuples

With the following code can you show how to use Swift CollectionType .filter .indexOf .map instance methods to find a value/values in an array of named tuples?

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs14CollectionType) was not enough.

```
import UIKit
class Foo {
    private var mData: String
    init(data: String) { mData = data }
    func printData() { print(mData) }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var myList = [(code:Int64, list: [Foo])]()
        let fooListA = [Foo(data: "A0"), Foo(data: "A1"), Foo(data: "A2")]
        let fooListB = [Foo(data: "B0"), Foo(data: "B1"), Foo(data: "B2")]
        let fooListC = [Foo(data: "C0"), Foo(data: "C1"), Foo(data: "C2")]
        let fooListD = [Foo(data: "D0"), Foo(data: "D1"), Foo(data: "D2")]
        myList.append((code: 10, list: fooListA))
        myList.append((code: 20, list: fooListB))
        myList.append((code: 30, list: fooListC))
        myList.append((code: 40, list: fooListD))

        // following lines cause errors     
        let foundItem: (code:Int64, list:[Foo]) = myList.filter { (Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool in
            if item.code = 20 {return true}
        }
        foundItem.list[1].printData() // prints 'B1'

        let foundItemIdx = myList.indexOf { (Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool in
            if item.code = 20 { return true}
        }
        print(foundItemIdx) // prints '1'

        // extra credit how does map work???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, there are a few things wrong, let's go through them step by step:

`filter` returns a potential collection of objects - still a collection. Therefore you cannot assign the result to something of type `(code:Int64, list:[Foo])` but `[(code:Int64, list:[Foo])]`. Or you omit the explicit type all together.

`(Self.Generator.Element)` is the generic type of the first parameter in the closure. Once again, you don't have to worry about its type, just write the name of the parameter -> `item`:

```
let foundItem = myList.filter { item -> Bool in
```

Your inner code in the filter does not always return a value - it only returns when the condition is met - you should **always** return something:

```
    if item.code == 20 {return true}; return false
```

Those statements can be simplified to

```
let foundItem = myList.filter { $0.code == 20 }
```

Following the first statement I wrote in the beginning, you cannot get a single item but a list returned. Therefore you must have access to the element at a specific index in that array:

```
foundItem[0].list[1].printData() // prints 'B1'
```

Or once again slightly more functional:

```
foundItem.forEach { $0.list[1].printData() }
```

Alternatively, if you are only interested in the first find you can write:

```
let foundItem = myList.filter { $0.code == 20 }.first
if let found = foundItem {
    found.list[1].printData() // prints 'B1'
}
```

Pretty much all of the above (except for the collection-stuff) is still true for the second "block":

```
let foundItemIdx = myList.indexOf { $0.code == 20 }
```

Regarding map: `map` lets you perform an operation on each element in the list returning a list which contains the result of the operation in the list instead of the original element:

```
let map2 = myList.map { $0.code / 10 }
let map3 = myList.map { $0.list[0].mData }

print(map2) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(map3) // ["A0", "B0", "C0", "D0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks luk2302 for making this easy to understand. For those looking for examples that quickly show how to use these methods here is the code rewritten with Luk2302's solutions:

```
var myList = [(code:Int64, list: [Foo])]()

let fooListA = [Foo(data: "A0"), Foo(data: "A1"), Foo(data: "A2")]
let fooListB = [Foo(data: "B0"), Foo(data: "B1"), Foo(data: "B2")]
let fooListC = [Foo(data: "C0"), Foo(data: "C1"), Foo(data: "C2")]
let fooListD = [Foo(data: "D0"), Foo(data: "D1"), Foo(data: "D2")]

myList.append((code: 10, list: fooListA))
myList.append((code: 20, list: fooListB))
myList.append((code: 30, list: fooListC))
myList.append((code: 40, list: fooListD))

// .filter - long way
let foundItem = myList.filter { item -> Bool in
    if item.code == 20 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
if let foundFirst = foundItem.first {
    foundFirst.list[1].printData() // prints 'B1'
}

// .filter - short way
if let foundItem = (myList.filter { $0.code == 20 }).first {
    foundItem.list[1].printData() // prints 'B1'
}

// .indexOf - long way
let foundItemIdx = myList.indexOf { item -> Bool in
    if item.code == 20 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
if let foundItemIndexUnwrapped = foundItemIdx {
    print(foundItemIndexUnwrapped) // prints '1'
}

// .indexOf - short way
if let foundItemIdxShortWay = (myList.indexOf { $0.code == 20 }) {
    print(foundItemIdxShortWay) // prints '1'
}

// map examples
let map2 = myList.map { $0.code / 10 }
let map3 = myList.map { $0.list[0].mData }

print(map2) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(map3) // ["A0", "B0", "C0", "D0"]
```